# Create function that can be run with any database

Tags: sql-server

How can I create a function that can be run against any database on my server?

Here's an example, I want to specify a column name to search for, and which database to search in:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_FindColumnsInAllTables 
(   
    @ColumnName NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
SELECT      
c.name  AS 'ColumnName'
,t.name AS 'TableName'
FROM        
sys.columns c
JOIN        
sys.tables  t   
ON 
c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       
c.name LIKE '%' + @ColumnName + '%'
)
```

Comment: Are you trying to check whether the database server is running?

Comment: You can't (at least not with standard t-sql), because this would require dynamic sql with is not allowed in a function. You could leverage OPENQUERY in your function but honestly this just seems like a lot of effort for little return.

Comment: WHy not do this as a stored proc instead?

Comment: If it was a Stored Procedure, what would be the syntax to call it, while passing the column name and database name as parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the excellent advice from HLGEM to use a procedure instead this is quite easy. This example not only works it is also sql injection proof. I use QUOTENAME around the database name itself and then parameterize the column name in the dynamic sql.

```
create procedure FindColumn
(
    @DBName sysname
    , @ColName sysname
) as

    declare @SQL nvarchar(max);

    if exists(select * from sys.databases where name = @DBName)
    begin

        set @SQL = 'select t.name as TableName
            , c.name as ColumnName 
            from ' + QUOTENAME(@DBName) + '.sys.tables t 
            join ' + QUOTENAME(@DBName) + '.sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id 
            where c.name = @ColName'

        exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@ColName sysname', @ColName = @ColName
    end
    else
        select 'Database not found'

GO


exec FindColumn 'YourDatabaseName', 'YourColumn'
```